# Android turns black on notifyDataSetChanged() in ExpandableListView

Tags: android, listview, user-interface, expandablelistview, expandablelistadapter

I'd like to apologize in advance if the question is a little vague but it's hard for me to provide a specific part of the code that could be responsible for what is going on.

I extended a BaseExpandableListAdapter to use in one of my Activities (StreamActivity) to populate an ExpandableListView. This Activity is part of an ActivityGroup. Then, it turned out I needed a very similar adapter for a different Activity (StreamUserActivity) that is not part of a group. I decided to extend my custom adapter further and only override certain methods that are different. The logic behind the row structure is the same for both adapters.

However, when I use the second adapter, the one for the stand-alone Activity, when I call notifyDataSetChanged(), before the list gets updated the screen goes black. On some occassions it is just a temporary blink, sometimes it stays that way. Then, if I scroll the list, it appears again but an element above the ExpandableListView does not reappear. Still, I can touch the active elements in this element and it reacts be transferring me to another Activity, as planned.

The StreamUserActivity is started from within the StreamActivity the following way:

```
Intent streamUserProfiletIntent = new Intent(this, StreamUserProfileActivity.class);
streamUserProfiletIntent.putExtra(StreamUserProfileActivity.USER_JID,
OpenfireRosterProvider.getInstance(getApplicationContext()).getCurrentUser().getJabberId());
startActivity(streamUserProfiletIntent);
```

This causes the screen to go black. However, if I start it like this:

```
Intent streamUserProfiletIntent = new Intent(this, StreamUserProfileActivity.class);
streamUserProfiletIntent.putExtra(StreamUserProfileActivity.USER_JID,
OpenfireRosterProvider.getInstance(getApplicationContext()).getCurrentUser().getJabberId());
startChildActivity("StreamUserProfiletIntent", streamUserProfiletIntent);
```

... there is no blinking but the new Activity is part of the ActivityGroup which is not what I need.

Any ideas as to what is causing this problem? Which part of the code could be responsible for this so that maybe I can share it.